# Point layer problem

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers

In QGIS 3.4 I've got a map with 2 vectors and 1 spreadsheet with point data that works fine.

I successfully added a second set of point data from a separate spreadsheet. I can zoom to the layer but I can't get the new layer to appear with the vector and first point data set. Had no problems with earlier version of 3.0.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Have you made sure all data is in the same CRS or enabled on-the-fly reprojection?

Comment: It's easy to accidentally reverse the X and Y coordinates when importing a CSV. Re-import the second layer and make sure the correct columns are assigned to the X and Y coordinates.